# How to get scrapyrt's POST meta data?

Tags: python, api, scrapy, web-crawler

In scrapyrt's POST documentation we can pass a JSON request like this, but how do you access the meta data like category and item in start_requests?

```
{
     "request": {
         "meta": {
            "category": "some category",
            "item": {
                "discovery_item_id": "999"
            }
        },
        , "start_requests": true
    },
    "spider_name": "target.com_products"
}
```

Reference: https://scrapyrt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#id1

Comment: Its supossed to access by response.meta["category"] but I'm stucked in the same problem, let me know if works for you,  will be answering if I found another way

Answer (score 4):

There is an unmerged PR in scrapyRT that adds support to pass extra parameters inthe POST request.

1) Patch resources.py file located in scrapyrt folder.
In my case was /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scrapyrt/resources.py

Replace with this code: https://github.com/gdelfresno/scrapyrt/commit/ee3be051ea647358a6bb297632d1ea277a6c02f8

2) Now your spider can access to the new parameters with self.param1

ScrapyRT curl example:

```
curl -XPOST -d '{
"spider_name":"quotes",
"start_requests": true,
"param1":"ok"}' "http://localhost:9080/crawl.json"
```

In your spider

```
def parse(self, response):
    print(self.param1)
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

To access the data like category in the start_requests method when using scrapyrt's POST method, you can utilize the "crawl_args" attribute as below:

```
import requests

body = {
    "spider_name": "spider_name",
    "start_requests": True,
    "crawl_args": {
        "category": "some category",
    }
}
data = requests.post("http://localhost:9080/crawl.json", json=body)
```

Now access the "category" key in your spider like,

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider_name"
    allowed_domains = ["*"]

    def start_requests(self):
        print(self.category)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=f"ww.example.com?cat={self.category}", callback=self.parse)
```